# Don't ask for confirmation when a mod deletes a flagged/negative-score post

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, vote-to-delete

When I delete a post directly from the flag queue, there is no confirmation and the post is immediately deleted. When I delete a post from the question view, I have to confirm the deletion in a dialog.

Deletion is something that can be undone with another click, so I don't really see the need for a confirmation dialog. Moderators delete posts quite often, so saving a click has some value. Allowing to undo an action is a far better solution than a dialog asking for confirmation, there is no reason for a confirmation dialog for actions that are not permanent. Ideally undoing a deletion in a very short timeframe would also avoid create a revision for the deletion/undeletion cycle.

An easy way to prevent erroneous deletion in most cases would to only omit the confirmation dialog for posts that are flagged or that have a negative score. This would prevent misclicks on most valuable posts.

Comment: The fact that deleting comments in question view doesn't require confirmation but deleting them from the flags queue does require confirmation bugs me more.

Comment: @animuson - That is the opposite from what is stated in the question. Which way round is it?

Comment: @Martin The question is about posts. My comment is about comments.

Comment: I usually don't ask for the reason for downvotes, but in this cases I'm rather puzzled about the reason. I can undo a deletion in one click, so misclicks are easily fixed. There is no value in the confirmation dialog, so I'd appreciate if someone would explain why this would be a bad idea.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd imagine it's a lot easier to misclick in the question view. There you get a tiny little link, whereas in the flags queue you get a big black button. It may be easy to fix, but if you don't make a mistake in the first place, then nothing needs to be fixed.

Comment: How often do you cancel? :) I think the main part of this I agree with is "a far better solution than a dialog", because chrome's dialog boxes are not very user friendly (loading at top:0px of the page). The chrome dialog popup can be a hindrance.

Answer (score 9):

Being able to undelete a post easily only helps if the user who accidentally deletes the post **knows they did it.** If they clicked by accident and never noticed, the post might never come back.

My experience with the Stack Exchange system and with web apps in general suggests to me that this is a realistic scenario, and that it might even happen somewhat regularly with the change you propose. But you have more information than I, being a moderator; so if I'm wrong, you may want to expand this meta question to explain why this isn't an issue.

It makes sense that when you're using the site in a way that's all about exercising moderator abilities, that there are fewer dialog boxes to check if you really mean to perform moderator actions. I don't see any real inconsistency here, and it seems to me that the current dialog box is necessary to protect users from accidental moderator actions **that are not subsequently noticed.**

Comment: +1 Especially when browsing on my IPad I have more than once managed to accidentally upvote/downvote posts and not noticed until much later (when the vote is locked in). Quite possibly this happened on other occasions that I didn't notice too.

Comment: Deletion is rather visible, as it changes the background of the entire post. And acting out of the queue is rather common on smaller sites, you just see more context.

Comment: @MadScientist What about the situation where (most likely on a mobile device) a user tries to switch to another tab or app, but ends up clicking *delete* and also switching to another tab or app?

Comment: On mobile the confirmation could simply be shown even for mods.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting and then undeleting reinitializes the state, same as closing and then reopening (or vice-versa).  You can't cancel *your* vote, only *all* of them.  If two other users voted to delete, I finish it off as a moderator, and either I didn't mean to or I have second thoughts, I undelete it and it has zero deletion votes.  Those other two users would have to see it and recast their votes.

I don't know if this is sufficient reason to require the confirmation -- I don't often find myself wanting to undo my deletion votes -- but it is a reason that posts are different from comments in this regard.